# CSS scale() cause resizable div to resize incorrectly

Tags: html, css

You can see the effect here:

[image]

I'm not sure why this happens after applying `scale(1.6)` to the parent(aka wrapper) `div`. Without scaling it works perfectly fine. I do not understand what's happening when you "scale". Are the dimension units scaled or the dimension (w x h) are scaled? How do you fix this?

PS: Calculation for this particular thing:

```
const width = <div width at mouse down> + (mousemoveX - <pageX at mosue down>)
const height = <div height at mouse down> + (mousemoveY - <pageY at mouse down>)
```

The HTML is simple:

```
<div style="scale(1.6)">
  <div id="resizable"></div>
</div>
```

**Edit**
Modified a fiddle ([original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219031/how-can-i-resize-a-div-by-dragging-just-one-side-of-it)) to show this effect [here](https://jsfiddle.net/abx72mje/). When scale is applied, the line jumps somewhere else and not where you release your mouse drag. This is exactly the same issue I have with my code. Scaling does something to positioning/sizing. Perhaps someone can explain this.

Comment: This is perhaps useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15467122/3168107